# Change from using a BufferedReader for a file, to a String

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have a working app that would take a text file, modify it in stages until it was neat and usable.
every stage would take in a file and modify it, then spit out a file that the next one would buffer in.

i am trying to make it cleaner so i want stop pulling in files, except the first one, and pass the output down the app as a string.
Using this code, how would i do that?

this is the second stage.

```
try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/Stage_Two.txt")));
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ALL|MESSAGE|Time|PAPER_MAIN|GSP");
                    if (pattern.matcher(line).find()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                    stringBuffer.append("\n");
                }
                BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:/Stage_Three.txt")));
                bwr.write(stringBuffer.toString());
                bwr.flush();
                bwr.close();
                // to see in console
                //System.out.println(stringBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

i have looked into InputStream, InputStreamReader, and Reader...but if its one of those i cant seem to make headway.

Comment: Are you just looking for a code review?

Comment: no, a direction to make the change from pulling in a file, to using a string.

Comment: Read something about the *decorator pattern*. Think about letting a different component, that is not associated with these "modifier classes", take care about reading and/or wrinting a file.

Comment: If you want a dirty hack then use [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) and [`StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html). Otherwise, just process use a `Stream<String>` from `Flies.lines()` and create a pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how a string would clean it up. The benefit of using readers and writers is that you don't need to have everything in memory. The following code will allow for very large files to be processed.

```
public void transformFile(File in, File out) throws IOException {

    /*
     * This method allocates the resources needed to perform the operation
     * and releases them once the operation is done. This mechanism is know
     * as a try-with-resource. After the try statement exits, the resources
     * are closed
     */

    try (BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
            Writer bout = new FileWriter(out)) {

        transformBufferedReader(bin, bout);
    }
}

private void transformBufferedReader(BufferedReader in, Writer out) throws IOException {
    /*
     * This method iterates over the lines in the reader and figures out if
     * it should be written to the file
     */

    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (isWriteLine(line)) writeLine(line, out);
    }
}

private boolean isWriteLine(String line) throws IOException {

    /*
     * This tests if the line should be written
     */

    return !line.matches("ALL|MESSAGE|Time|PAPER_MAIN|GSP");
}

private void writeLine(String line, Writer writer) throws IOException {

    /*
     * Write a line out to the writer
     */

    writer.append(line);
    writer.append('\n');
}
```

If you insist on using string, you could add the following method.

```
public String transformString(String str) {
    try (BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str));
            Writer bout = new StringWriter()) {

        transformBufferedReader(bin, bout);
        return bout.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("the string readers shouln't be throwing IOExceptions");
    }
}
```